# Implementing Infinite Carousel in Android

Tags: android

I would like to implement an infinite carousel. I do not want to use a viewpager, that doesn't seem to work. I want the item that is in view to be enlarged and when I swipe away from it, for it to decrease in size and the next one becomes enlarged. Any links, or past questions I can got to. I've searched all over stackoverflow but have not found something close or similar to what I want. A good example would be the view of the albums in a phone music player in landscape mode.

Comment: Google "Android carousel" and the magic happen ... http://tech.leolink.net/2013/02/create-simple-infinite-carousel-in.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no native implementation of this component, you'll need to implement it yourself and SO is not the place to explain you how.

Another alternative is finding a library or custom component done by another person for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean carousel ?

i found mine at this page
http://regupathybalan.blogspot.fr/2013/04/carousel-tutorial.html

I use this exemple but items is limited :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel